# How do I represent an empty Char in Scala?

Tags: scala, char, default-value

```
val mychar=''
```

Does not compile and results in the following error:

> error: unclosed character literal

```
val mychar='a'
```

etc is fine. I've tried playing around with converting "" to char but without much luck

Comment: That is not scala specific. Did you try this in java? Are you looking for a default value for a non initialized char? Since java has primitive types: char a; print(a) would assign the int value 0 to a and it's respectively char mapping. So sanely Option[Char] is a good approach. With None as empty, non initialized value and everything else Some(a)

Answer (score 34):

There is no such thing as an "empty" Character -- what is an "empty" Integer? :)

The closest is the [NUL-character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character), which has an ordinal value of 0 (`'\0'`, `0.toChar`, `0: Char`)...

...or perhaps [`Option[Char]`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/rc/scala/Option.html) would be able to better-describe the situation?

```
val someChar = Some('a')
val noChar = None: Option[Char]
val maybeChar = List(someChar, noChar)((Math.random * 2).toInt)
// ...
```

Happy coding.

Comment: ∅ takes issue with your first statement.

Comment: @Kim: I think he is talking about `∅` function from Scalaz.

Comment: `assert('\0' == 0)` passes so `val mychar: Char = 0` also works

Comment: @missingfaktor, This is funny. My first comment was just a bad attempt at a joke on the fact that there is a unicode symbol for "empty". May be I should have said "*There is no such thing as an empty Character* - 'Hey I exist!' - signed empty char ∅"... Kim then replies with what seems is a retort - which I don't get. Then you come in and indicate there is actually a ∅ method in scalaz! End of course, you're right! `'A' |+| ∅[Char]` returns `'A'`. My comment does not deserve any upvote, your does.

Comment: LOL! Talk about misinterpretations!

Comment: @KimStebel Actually, he was saying that ∅ _is_ the "empty character" -- the character that represents the concept empty. In math.

Comment: @huynhjl: I was talking about the empty set, which is neither a character nor an integer. And since it does not have any members, all of them (i.e. none) take issue with the first statement.

Comment: answering question and adding some little comment to great @user166390 explanation NUL-character is cool counterpart of empty string but has some small (but in my case big) caveat: it isn't printable I guess. When you have something like:
`println(s"key: $key, value: $value")` and `val key = '\0'` then you will see `> key: ` on console only. And actually it makes sense because it is terminating character and all after that is skipped. So be careful about that and follow @user166390 advice to use `Option[Char]` or use any printable character as your "default" one.

Answer (score 1):

im was trying same thing i had to return empty char or something like thats '' so what i did when val c : char = '\0'

```
val c : char = " ".charAt(0)
```